# AllenNLP - configuration to write test set metrics to Tensorboard

Tags: allennlp

When running the AllenNLP `train` or `evaluate` CLI commands, is there a configuration option (in the json/jsonnet file) to write **test set** evaluation metrics to Tensorboard?

If not, how can I do it in my own script?

Thanks in advance for your time and help. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* pass in your test set as a validation set in your config file. However, treating the test set as an evaluation set is not recommended.

You can also use the `allennlp evaluate` command, which dumps the metrics to a user-specified output file.